# Do calculations on Spark and store results in database or Spark DataFrame with PySpark?

Tags: python, database, apache-spark, pyspark

So, I have some data loaded in spark data-frames (I am using PySpark). I do some operations over them, such as `join` and then `groupy`, etc and then I get a result for each group.

I want to take that result and use it to build another data-frame. I have read that data-frames are immutables, so a spark data-frame might not be the best choice.

What is the next best alternative? Should I write my results to a database, such as RDS?

The alternative would be to create a row out of each results and do a union with my results data-frame.

Comment: why do you need another dataframe? every transformation returns a new dataframe, you can use it for next level of operations.

Comment: Well I need to store the results on disk anyway, so that a front end application can access the results.
Also, say I apply a filter, and then do a  groupby, then do a sum over the results, and then apply another filter, and then groupby, sum, etc. I need to make a row out of these results, and then insert into a database or dataframe (which will later be inserted into a database)

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit enter. I just made some edits to complete my comment.

Comment: If I understood you correctly then are you trying something like this: **pseudo code** `final-dataframe = BaseDataFrame->group by ->sum ->other aggregations/filters -> ;final-dataframe.save ; final-dataframe->other transformations`

Comment: yes thats right.

Comment: great! could you please add code snippet what you have tried?